# How to add together elements of an Array List

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to make a cash register program that takes in an array of integer prices and then adds them together to get the total sale price. Here's the snippet of my code that's important

```
do
{
  System.out.print("Enter the integer price: $ ");
  int i = in.nextInt();
  Prices.add(i);
  System.out.println();
}
while(in.hasNextInt());

for(int i=0; i<Prices.size(); i++)
{
  int Total = Prices.get(i) + Prices.get(i+1);
}
System.out.println(Total);
```

My error says "Total cannot be resolved to a variable" and earlier it didn't like when i tried to make the increment in the loop i+2 instead of i++. Can someone help I have no idea how to add together these variables

Is this the right track?

```
for(int i=0; i<Prices.size(); i++)
{
  int Total = 0;
  int Total = Total + Prices.get(i);
}
```

Comment: You should not start a variable name with an uppercase. It's confusing because uppercase is usually for class name, not variable name.

Answer (score 2):

No need of an array or list.

```
int total = 0;   
do  
{   
  System.out.print("Enter the integer price: $ ");  
  int i = in.nextInt();  
  total += i;  
  System.out.println();  
}  
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Excellent improvement assuming the (I'm guessing) homework assignment doesn't explicitly call for utilizing `ArrayList`

Comment: It should be a while loop, not a do while loop. Otherwise you will get an exception if there is not a single number in the input.

Comment: Two upvotes for code that I'm pretty sure won't compile.

Comment: You left out the `while` part of the `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing 2 things wrong here:

```
int Total = Prices.get(i) + Prices.get(i+1);
```

You're declaring `Total` inside the `for` loop. Do that outside with a default value of `0`. Then you are adding the values of the current iteration and the next iteration. You just want to do `Total = Total + Prices.get(i);` or `Total += Prices.get(i);`.

Preferably, you can do it all as you get the values. There's no need for the additional list `Prices`:

```
int total = 0;
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter the integer price: $ ");
    int i = in.nextInt();
    total += i;
    //prices.add(i);//if you still want to keep the list
    System.out.println();
}
while(in.hasNextInt());
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `Total` in a different scope than you are trying to use it. Additionally the logic in your loop is flawed for summing the prices. Try this:

```
int Total = 0;
for(int i=0; i<Prices.size(); i++)
{
  Total = Total + Prices.get(i);
}
System.out.println(Total);
```